# Can a Graph API token be converted into a SharePoint REST API token?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

It's a long shot, but maybe someone figured it out.

Is it possible to make a request, or a bunch of requests, to gain access to SharePoint REST API if what I have is a Graph API access token? (Let's assume I can have any scopes and admin level user is giving permissions for the Graph authorization)

Answer (score 1):

@naugtur,

I understand you want to you access multiple resources but not want to prompt login window again. You can consider using following approaches:

1. [Refresh Token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens): one Access token can only access one resource, but refresh token is against with multiple resource. Refresh tokens are valid for all resources that your client has already been given consent to access - thus, a refresh token issued on a request for `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` can be used to request a new access token for `resource=https://contoso.com/api`.
2. [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow): The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API. The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain

BR